# how to assign new values to variables in predefined equation?

Tags: python, variables, sympy

for predefined equations,assigning new values to variables do not changes value of equation.
how can i assign new values to variables so that i will get appropriate value of equation and not the previous one

```
a,b,c,d,e,f=sympy.symbols('abcdef')
a,b=c,d

e=a+b #equation 
print e
c+d #value of eqn
a,b=d,f
print e
c+d  #not d+f
```

Comment: Discussion of your issue: http://docs.sympy.org/gotchas.html#variables-assignment-does-not-create-a-relation-between-expressions

Comment: @PreludeAndFugue: the link is now broken. Do you have any new reference, perhaps?

Comment: Updated link: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#variables-assignment-does-not-create-a-relation-between-expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps use [substitution](http://docs.sympy.org/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs) instead of equality:

```
import sympy
a,b,c,d,e,f=sympy.symbols('abcdef')
e=a+b #equation 
print e.subs([(a,c),(b,d)])
# c + d
print e.subs([(a,d),(b,f)])
# d + f
```

Comment: getting this
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable